# Error while changing/altering column name in MySql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to change column Customer_email to customerEmail but it gives error

The code which is giving error is

```
alter table getCustomer
change Customer_email customerEmail varchar;
```

The code is working fine with "int" type columns.

[image: Changing Column name error]

Comment: Also, you should never ever store the customer's password, not in plain text, not encrypted.

Comment: Hover with the mouse over the marked word to see a hint what could be wrong. It should give you the message that an opening paren is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the type VARCHAR, you have to give the maximum length of the string, e.g., `VARCHAR(50)`.